# How to write program in Spark to replace word

Tags: scala, hadoop, apache-spark

it is easy for Hadoop to use `.replace()` for example

```
String[] valArray = value.toString().replace("\N", "")
```

But it dosen't work in Spark,I write Scala in Spark-shell like below

```
val outFile=inFile.map(x=>x.replace("\N",""))
```

So,how to deal with it?

Comment: What's the problem? That should work fine in spark.

Comment: it reminds that " error: value replace is not a member of Array[java.lang.String]" @lmm

Comment: For some reason your `x` is an `Array[String]`. How did you get it like that? You can `.toString.replace` it if you like, but that will probably not get you what you want (and would give the wrong output in java anyway); you probably want to do another layer of `map`, `inFile.map(x => x.map(_.replace("\N","")))

Comment: @lmm Could you put that in an answer that can be accepted?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For some reason your `x` is an `Array[String]`. How did you get it like that? You can `.toString.replace` it if you like, but that will probably not get you what you want (and would give the wrong output in java anyway); you probably want to do another layer of map, `inFile.map(x => x.map(_.replace("\N","")))`