# value map is not a member of org.apache.spark.sql.Row

Tags: scala, twitter, apache-spark

I have tweets from Twitter in the complex schema and I am trying to extract text from those tweets and then clean the data for doing further analysis. I am running an SQL query to extract tweets and then when I  tried to use replaceAll or replace to clean the tweets it kept throwing an exception

> value map is not a member of org.apache.spark.sql.Row

So I tried to look for a solution and came across this [How to write program in Spark to replace word](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27633453/how-to-write-program-in-spark-to-replace-word)  which is sort of similar but related to a string issue. I tried to implement it with the nested map but doesn't seem to work.

Here's my code snippet:

```
 val tweets = sc.textFile(tweetInput).filter(l => l.trim !="")
 val tweetTable = sqlContext.jsonRDD(tweets)
 tweetTable.registerTempTable("tweetTable")
 sqlContext.cacheTable("tweetTable")

 // read all tweets from input files 
    val trimmed_tweets = sqlContext.sql("SELECT text FROM tweetTable WHERE text <> '' ")
      .map(x => x.map(_.replace("""([\p{Punct}&&[^.@]]|\b\p{IsLetter}{1,2}\b)\s*""", "")))
      .toLowerCase()
      .filter(_.nonEmpty)
      .flatMap(x=>x)
```

I also am having trouble using the saveAsTextFile option for trimmed_tweets because of saveAsTextFile also not being a member of org.apache.spark.sql.Row

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that your operating on a `Row` instead of a `String`. You first have to extract the tweet text from the `Row` which is stored in the first column.

```scala
 val trimmed_tweets = sqlContext.sql("SELECT text FROM tweetTable WHERE text <> '' ")
  .map(row => row.getString(0).replace("""([\p{Punct}&&[^.@]]|\b\p{IsLetter}{1,2}\b)\s*""", "")))
  .toLowerCase()
  .filter(_.nonEmpty)
```